# Cambiar de color de ion-item ionic

Tags: ionic, angularjs-2.0, typescript, ionic2

Estoy intentando cambiar el color de ion-item de ionic al pulsa sobre el, estoy empezando con angular e ionic y nose muy bien como hacerlo. Se que habría que pasarle el id al metedo click y una vez ahi cambiarlo, pero nose bien como hacerlo. gracias

html

```
 <ion-header>
<ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
        Aplicacion
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
 </ion-header>

  <ion-content padding>

<ion-list *ngFor="let a of alumnos">
    <ion-item  color='dark' (click)='falta(id)'>
        <ion-avatar item-left>
            <img src="img/YO.png">
        </ion-avatar>
        <h2>{{a}}</h2>
    </ion-item> 
</ion-list>
```

.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
 })
 export class HomePage {


private alumnos = ["jose","yeste"];

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

}

falta(id:string){
    console.log(id);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_color.asp

Para modificar estilos de tu aplicación lo puedes hacer igual que una pagina web.

```
falta(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.color = "#ff0000";
}
```